# Imbalanced classes

Tags: classification, class-imbalance, graph-neural-network

I am currently dealing with imbalanced classes in my case of binary classification, where one class represents only 4% of the other class. To address this issue, here is the approach I have taken:

1. Splitting the lower class into training and validation sets.
2. Choosing the same number of elements from the lower class as in the training set.
3. Creating a training set with an equal number of samples from both classes (50-50 ratio).
4. Allocating all the remaining elements to the validation set.

For instance, if I have 100 elements, there would be 4 elements in the lower class. These elements could be divided into 3 for training and 1 for validation. This means that I would train the model using 3+3 elements, while all the remaining elements would be used for validation (94 elements where 1 from lower class and 93 from the other class).

Now, the question is whether this approach is effective in addressing the problem. Perhaps it is better to maintain some level of class imbalance even in the training set, as the current method is resulting in a high number of false positives.

Is this a suitable solution to tackle the problem at hand, or would it be more advantageous to preserve some level of class imbalance in the training data to mitigate the issue of false positives?

Comment: Suggested reading: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/357466/are-unbalanced-datasets-problematic-and-how-does-oversampling-purport-to-he

https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6349/profusion-of-threads-on-imbalanced-data-can-we-merge-deem-canonical-any